# IntelliJ not creating directory in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm having a weird error.

I'm running IntelliJ in Ubuntu

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create the directory [/logs] to use as the base directory
```

Even tough the Logs directory is being properly generated.

It seems like tomcat cannot access that directory. Any ideas?

Already did a fresh installation and started a new repo of the project.

Comment: (1) If the log directory is `/logs`,  you must create it first( use `sudo mkdir /logs`m then `sudo chown $USER:$USER /logs`, then it will OK. (2) But I guess your log config is set wrong directory. try set it to `${catalina.base}/logs`

Comment: Nop did not work for me :C

Comment: (1) please show your config file. (2) is this a web application ? or spring boot application ?  (3) or just find '/logs' , and change it  to `logs`. do not include `/`

Comment: ok @life888888 that tweak worked, altough it led me to a different problem, but thanks for that.